# jquery custom scrollbar doesn't update

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

jquery custom scrollbar doesn't update

Hi everybody

I'm using a jquery custom scrollbar horizontal plugin
in special time I want my scroll updated

this is my code

```
$(".content_6 .entryBody").append($('.NewEntry').html());
$('.NewEntry').html('');
LoadEntry(1);
$(".content_6").mCustomScrollbar("update");
```

LoadEntry function , does something for .entryBody size , it is not important , what is important is in this code , the last line just doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the height or the minHeight of .content_6 and the overflow to auto or hidden?

Comment: custom scrollbar work well , when i want to update it , it is dont work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What does the css for .content6 look like? A fiddle would be useful so we could see what's going on.